# How to find the range of $\frac1{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$?

Tags: functions

My textbook says the range is $(0, \infty)$ and I truly do understand how this answer is coming but what is going wrong with my method.

Let $f(x) = \dfrac {1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}} = y$

Squaring both sides,

$x^2-1=\dfrac {1}{y^2}$

$x^2 = \dfrac {y^2+1}{y^2}$

For $x$ to be real, $y \neq 0$; hence range = $\mathbb {R} - \{{0}\}$

Note : Here √ is the principal square root function.

Comment: As in your previous question: What is the domain?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  The principal square root is non-negative, so the range is non-negative, and $1/\sqrt{x^2-1}$ can't be $0$

Comment: @Jan the domain is (-∞,-1) U (1,∞).

Comment: @Brian yes that is exactly what I am asking , why is the range restricted to (0,∞).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principal square root function is non-negative, so $\sqrt{x^2-1}\ge0$.

In fact, for your domain, $x^2>1,$ so $\sqrt{x^2-1}>0$.

Therefore $1/\sqrt{x^2-1}>0.$

Comment: But where is my method going wrong?

Comment: You should have stopped at $y=1/\sqrt{x^2-1}$ and analyzed that, as I did.  When you square both sides of an equation, you could lose information.  For example $(-2)^2=2^2$, but that does not mean $-2=2$

Comment: Hmm that makes sense thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)=x^2-1$ in the square root must be positive and different from $0$ (the denominator can't be $0$), so I have: $f(x)>0$ and so $$x^2-1>0$$ The solutions are: $x<-1 \lor x>1$.

The function $g(x)=1/f(x)$ is always positive, so the range is: $$I_g={\forall y \in R | y\geq0}$$

Comment: That is the domain of the function ; I'm asking about the range.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for the function to be well defined you need $x^2>1$

The domain of your function is $$(-\infty, -1)\cup (1,\infty)$$

The range of your function is therefore $$(0,\infty)$$